# Handling different input fields using Robot Framework

Tags: selenium2, browser-automation, robotframework

I am writing an automation test script using Robot Framework & Selenium2Library for testing our web application (I am writing test cases in  `.txt` format)

I am having a problem on handling two different input fields using Robot Framework. I have to change the values of these two input types using RF.
So far I couldn't find any specific keywords to perform this functionalities.

These are the different input fields I have to test:

1. Range Input Field

[image]

html code :  `<input type="range" id="fontSize" min="8" max="20" step="1" value="12">`

Here is the testing scenario : I have to move the slider to a different location & I have to check the value of input range field

2. Color Picker

[image]

Here is the testing scenario: I have to move the pointer through out the color picker window & Select a particular color from the color picker ( I have to store the selected color into a variable for future reference)

I didn't get any particular solution for handling this issue.  Is there any keywords in robot framework to test 'Range Input Field' & 'Color Picker'? Can you please suggest asolution for this issue

Comment: Can you point to a publicly available sample of the controls, so we can see and try possible solutions? Apart from that, yes, robotframework/Selenium don't have such high-level keywords and methods. I doubt any generic framework does - they have to be constructed for the particular SUT, according to the functionality it provides.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, have you found a way to solve it

Answer (score 1):

For `input[type="range"]`, following keyword `Set Range` can be used. I have tested this with [this](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FEXUIFH94YGB) HTML and the used the attached test case for testing the keyword. Just add the following code snippet in `Selenium2Library/keyword/_element.py` and `import math`, time library.

```
import math
import time

def set_range(self, locator, val):
# The adjustment helper to drag the slider thumb
    def adjust(deltax):
        if deltax < 0:
            deltax = int(math.floor(min(-1, deltax)))
        else:
            deltax = int(math.ceil(max(1, deltax)))
        ac = ActionChains(self._current_browser())
        ac.click_and_hold(None)
        ac.move_by_offset(deltax, 0)
        ac.release(None)
        ac.perform()

    el = self._element_find(locator, True, True)
    minval = float(el.get_attribute("min") or 0)
    maxval = float(el.get_attribute("max") or 100)
    v = max(0, min(1, (float(val) - minval) / (maxval - minval)))
    width = el.size["width"]
    target = float(width) * v
    
    ac = ActionChains(self._current_browser())
    
    # drag from min to max value, to ensure oninput event
    ac.move_to_element_with_offset(el, 0, 1)
    ac.click_and_hold()
    ac.move_by_offset(width, 0)
    
    # drag to the calculated position
    ac.move_to_element_with_offset(el, target, 1)
    
    ac.release()
    ac.perform()
    
    # perform a binary search and adjust the slider thumb until the value matches
    minguess = 0
    maxguess = 0
    while True:
        curval = el.get_attribute("value")
        if float(curval) == float(val):
            return True
        prev_guess = target
        if float(curval) < float(val):
            minguess = target
            target += (maxguess - target) / 2
        else:
           maxguess = target
           target = minguess + (target - minguess) / 2
        deltax = target-prev_guess
        if abs(deltax) < 0.5:
            break # cannot find a way, fallback to javascript.
    
        time.sleep(0.1) # Don't consume CPU too much
    
        adjust(deltax)
    
    # Finally, if the binary search algoritm fails to achieve the final value
    # we'll revert to the javascript method so at least the value will be changed
    # even though the browser events wont' be triggered.
    
     # Fallback
    self._current_browser().execute_script("arguments[0].value=arguments[1];", el, val)
    curval = el.get_attribute("value")
    if float(curval) == float(val):
        return True
    else:
        raise Exception("Can't set value %f for the element." % val)
```

Here's the test case:

```
 *** Settings ***

Documentation  TC1: A test case to set range

Resource       common_resource.txt


*** Test Cases ***

A test case to set range
    Open Browser  url=https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FEXUIFH94YGB
    Click Element  css=button[onclick="submitTryit(1)"]
    Select Frame  css=iframe#iframeResult
    Wait Until Page Contains Element  css=input[type="range"]
    Set Range  css=input[type="range"]  8
    Set Range  css=input[type="range"]  20
```

Reference: [Selenium: How to automate html5 input range element on Webdriver](http://blog.usetrace.com/selenium-how-to-automate-html5-input-range-element-on-webdriver/)